# Gatling goes over the number of users

Tags: gatling

I am using `constantUsersPerSec` to inject users in my simulation scrip, according to the docs I was expecting to see that number of users/requests being performed, so that rate would act as limit (and a baseline too).
However, in some situations (seems random), the number of requests go over this limit.
This is the metrics from my load balancer:

[image]

In there, we can see a drop of the requests and then a peak that goes over the rate.

To compare, this is a normal run:

[image]

The gatling injection script:

```
val scenario: ScenarioBuilder = scenario("Test")
    .exec(doHttpRequest())

setUp(
    scenario.inject(
       constantUsersPerSec(30).during(5.minutes),
       constantUsersPerSec(60).during(10.minutes)
    ).protocols(httpProtocol)
  )
```

Gatling version: 3.7.3.
The injector host is a m5.large EC2 instance.
The CPU utilization for both executions is not that high:

[image]

Network out (bytes):

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You should probably look at your infrastructure: the injector host, the network between the injector and your LB, etc. Are you able to reproduce with Gatling Cloud?

Comment: The injector host is posting directly to the load balancer, both are on the same network. Not sure what I should be looking at the host itself though

Comment: CPU usage, bandwidth, IOPS

Comment: I've just added screenshots for the CPU and network out metrics for the injector host when both load tests were performed. They are both similar and nothing out of the ordinary.

Comment: Honestly no idea. No such issue has ever been reported. We would need a reproducer in order to investigate. But consider that Gatling might not be the issue but possibly the messenger.